# jQuery not working in IE6 at all

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6

I'm at a complete loss here. A client of mine uses IE6 internally and for some reason even the simplest jQuery does not work. Here is the code that will not work.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(function() {
            alert("alert from jQuery");
        });

        $(document).ready(function() {
            alert("alert from doc.ready");
        });


    </script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I know that there are a lot of issues with IE6. Ive tried a bunch of the workarounds that I found on the internet (like putting the script at the bottom of the page, removing the type attr) and no dice. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try putting `$(document).ready` first. Try just doing alert without the dom being loaded. Make sure you're linking to correct/working jquery repository. Does it work in other browsers?

Comment: jQuery.com says: *IE 6.0+* and I believe them. So please post whole HTML document (form `<!DOCTYPE html>` to `</html>`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will not work in a lot of browsers actually because you've not included the script properly. You must do the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
```

The `script` tags must be done as above or the script will **not** be included.

Comment: Correct.  This one bit me a few times.

Comment: @Peter J - Same. I think it's happened to everyone at least once.

Comment: On my desk there is a small list of mistakes that I tend to make from time to time. Each time I make a mistake that's on the list, I force myself to turn off my monitor and walk away for a few minutes.

This mistake is on that list.

Comment: You hit it on the nose....closing the script tag as you describe above corrected the problem. Thanks very much.